# OpenID Connect & Mobile Authentication Options for AppEngine for apps with multiple simultaneous login

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-oauth, google-identity-toolkit

Does Google Identity Toolkit support OpenID Connect? Does it support multiple simultaneous logins (can you be logged in with both Facebook and Google+)? Twitter isn't supported, so can you add your own identity service to it?

I'm setting up an AppEngine server for a mobile Android application that will let users log in via Google, Twitter, or Digits (Twitter's SMS authentication service). They must log in with 1 of the 3 providers, but they can additionally link the other two for enhanced social features. I'm trying to figure out the best approach to take to implement this.

Does AppEngine have built in authentication/authorization support for OpenID Connect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Google Identity Toolkit supports OpenID Connect (for Google identity provider).

While it is true that Twitter is not yet supported by Google Identity Toolkit, we are working on adding such functionality and hope to be launching it soon -- stay tuned :)

As per your question around AppEngine's OpenID Connect support, my understanding is that there is currently none (only OpenID 2.0 is currently supported, see [AppEngine dev docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs)).

Hope that helps!